# Bind Pie Series to a checkbox - c# (LiveCharts)

Tags: c#, binding, livecharts

I have a simple program with a checkbox, textbox, and a pieChart.

I want when i press the checkbox the color and text of the textbox will be change

as well as some property of the pieChart.

When i tried to change to the property to pieChart itself it worked fine.

But i try to change a property inside it's collection im getting an error

> Cannot find source for binding with reference

**My Code**

```
<Window x:Class="TestLiveCharts.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
        x:Name="UC">   


    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox x:Name="cbSample" Content="Hello" Grid.Row="0" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0" FontSize="48"  Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        //--> this is where i get my error
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbSample, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True"> 
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes!" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
        <lvc:PieChart  Grid.Row="2" x:Name="chart" Hoverable="True" HoverPushOut="6" >

                <lvc:PieChart.Series>
                <lvc:PieSeries Values="1"  Fill="Black"  StrokeThickness="0">
                    <lvc:PieSeries.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="lvc:PieSeries">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType={x:Type CheckBox}}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="10"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </lvc:PieSeries.Style>
                </lvc:PieSeries>
                    <lvc:PieSeries Values="1"  Fill="Green"  StrokeThickness="0"/>
                    <lvc:PieSeries Values="1"  Fill="Yellow"   StrokeThickness="0"/>
                    <lvc:PieSeries Values="1"  Fill="DarkCyan"   StrokeThickness="0"/>
                    <lvc:PieSeries Values="1"  Fill="Gray"   StrokeThickness="0"/>
                </lvc:PieChart.Series>
            </lvc:PieChart>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bind the IsChecked property of the checkbox to a value in your viewmodel, and  bind your datatrigger to this same value in the viewmodel.

Alternatively, binding to the ElementName works in both cases - try this:

```
<Window x:Class="TestLiveCharts.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
    x:Name="UC">


<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbSample" Content="Hello" Grid.Row="0" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0" FontSize="48"  Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbSample, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes!" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <lvc:PieChart  Grid.Row="2" x:Name="chart" Hoverable="True" HoverPushOut="6" >
        <lvc:PieChart.Series>
            <lvc:PieSeries Values="1" >
                <lvc:PieSeries.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="lvc:PieSeries">
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="0"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbSample, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="10"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </lvc:PieSeries.Style>
            </lvc:PieSeries>
            <lvc:PieSeries Values="1"  Fill="Green"  StrokeThickness="0"/>
            <lvc:PieSeries Values="1"  Fill="Yellow"   StrokeThickness="0"/>
            <lvc:PieSeries Values="1"  Fill="DarkCyan"   StrokeThickness="0"/>
            <lvc:PieSeries Values="1"  Fill="Gray"   StrokeThickness="0"/>
        </lvc:PieChart.Series>
    </lvc:PieChart>

</Grid>
```

Clicking the check box will give you this result:
[image]

Or try by binding to viewmodel:

```
<Window x:Class="StackoverflowTest.MainWindow"   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
x:Name="UC">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbSample" Content="Hello" Grid.Row="0" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0" FontSize="48"  Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Checked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes!" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <lvc:PieChart  Grid.Row="2" x:Name="chart" Hoverable="True" HoverPushOut="6" >
        <lvc:PieChart.Series>
            <lvc:PieSeries Values="1" >
                <lvc:PieSeries.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="lvc:PieSeries">
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="0"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Checked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="10"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </lvc:PieSeries.Style>
            </lvc:PieSeries>
            <lvc:PieSeries Values="1"  Fill="Green"  StrokeThickness="0"/>
            <lvc:PieSeries Values="1"  Fill="Yellow"   StrokeThickness="0"/>
            <lvc:PieSeries Values="1"  Fill="DarkCyan"   StrokeThickness="0"/>
            <lvc:PieSeries Values="1"  Fill="Gray"   StrokeThickness="0"/>
        </lvc:PieChart.Series>
    </lvc:PieChart>

</Grid>
```

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace StackoverflowTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        bool _checked = true;
        public bool Checked
        {
            get
            {
                return _checked;
            }
            set
            {
                _checked = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Checked));
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: same result(i also tried to remove the RelativeSource). please note that the DataTrigger of the CheckBox is still working properly(i also change it to work with the same isChecked property  in my view model)

Comment: getting the same error, i even created a new project(.NET 4.6.2) and I'm using liveCharts version 0.9.7. **UPDATE** IF i'm changing the value from true to false i do see the change in the preview but when i run the program the problem remians. and after i run the preview return to as it was StrokeThickness = 0

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.6.1 and Livecharts.wpf v 0.9.7. I have found the pure XAML version to be slightly unreliable for reasons I haven't tracked down yet, but binding to a viewmodel works every time - I've added this version too for completeness.

Comment: Thanks, its look very similar to my solution, i will check what is missing in my code